# Change navigation bar icons in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, navigation, pager

I want to change the order of the navigation button icons for the add, update and delete button in a [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start). How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reorder the navigation buttons just by usage of the functions like [jQuery.insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/), [jQuery.before](http://api.jquery.com/before/), [jQuery.insertAfter](http://api.jquery.com/insertAfter/) or [jQuery.after](http://api.jquery.com/after/). It's only important to know the ids of the cells used for the standard buttons. The ids will be build from the prefixes "add_", "del_", "search_", "refresh_", "edit_" and the id of the grid. For example if you have the grid with the id="list", then the cell of Delete button has the `id="del_list"`.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/ReorderButtons.htm) uses the following code

```js
$("#del_list").insertBefore("#add_list");
$("#search_list").insertBefore("#del_list");
$("#refresh_list").insertBefore("#search_list");
```

to reorder the navigator buttons to the following:

[image]

Comment: I want to change the order of `view` icon after `refresh`, then how can I do that ?

Comment: @BhavikAmbani: "View" button has `id="view_list"`. So you can use the same methods to reorder the "View" button. For example `$("#refresh_list").insertBefore("#view_list");` will place "Refresh" button before "View" button. In the same way `$("#view_list").insertAfter("#refresh_list");` place "View" button after "Refresh" button.