# JQGrid - cannot add a row to the grid with a parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I want to add a row to a jqgrid. In doing so, I want to send a parameter but I cannot get the syntax right, I tried using AddRowParams;

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Maintenance
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Maintenance of Departments and Divisions</legend>
        <p>Add, edit or delete a department or division: <%: Html.DropDownList("BusinessUnitTypes")%></p>
        <p>To amend the department or division, select the row, make the change and then press the return key.</p>
        <table id="list" class="scroll"></table>
        <div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;font-size: 11px;"></div>
    </fieldset>
    <!-- "BusinessUnitTypeId", (SelectList)ViewData["BusinessUnitTypes"] -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { reloadGrid(); });

    $('#BusinessUnitTypes').change(function () {
        $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid");
    });

    function reloadGrid() {
        var lastSelectedId;

        $('#list').jqGrid({
            url: '<%: Url.Action("GetBusinessUnits", "BusinessUnit")%>',
            postData: {
                businessUnitTypeId: function () { return $("#BusinessUnitTypes option:selected").val(); }
            },
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['ID', 'Name', 'Fax', 'Email', "Employees"],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'BusinessUnitId', index: 'BusinessUnitId', width: 25, editable: false, key: true },
                { name: 'BusinessUnitName', index: 'BusinessUnitName', width: 200, editable: true, edittype: 'text' },
                { name: 'Fax', index: 'Fax', width: 80, align: 'right', edittype: 'text', editable: true },
                { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 200, editable: true, edittype: 'text' },
                { name: 'NumberOfEmployees', index: 'NumberOfEmployees', width: 70, editable: false}],
            rowNum: 20,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: '#pager',
            gridview: true,
            sortname: 'BusinessUnitName',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "asc",
            caption: "Edit",
            height: 575,
            onSelectRow: function (id) {
                if (id && id !== lastSelectedId) {
                    $(this).restoreRow(lastSelectedId);
                    lastSelectedId = id;
                }
                $(this).editRow(id, true);
            },
            editurl: '<%: Url.Action("Save", "BusinessUnit")%>'
        });
        $('#list').jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
                { add: true, del: true, edit: false, search: false },
                {},
                { width: 'auto', url: '<%:Url.Action("Add", "BusinessUnit")%>', addRowParams: { extraparam: { businessUnitTypeId: function () { return $("#BusinessUnitTypes option:selected").val(); } } } },
                { width: 'auto', url: '<%:Url.Action("Delete", "BusinessUnit")%>' });
    }

</script>
</asp:Content>
```

EDIT - I have updated my code to the following, although for now it still does not work - see discussion with Oleg.

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Maintenance
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Maintenance of Departments and Divisions</legend>
        <p>Add, edit or delete a department or division: <%: Html.DropDownList("BusinessUnitTypes")%></p>
        <p>To amend the department or division, select the row, make the change and then press the return key.</p>
        <table id="list" class="scroll"></table>
        <div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;font-size: 11px;"></div>
    </fieldset>
    <!-- "BusinessUnitTypeId", (SelectList)ViewData["BusinessUnitTypes"] -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { reloadGrid(); });

    $('#BusinessUnitTypes').change(function () {
        $("#list").trigger("reloadGrid");
    });

        function reloadGrid() {
            //var businessUnitTypeId = function() { return $("#BusinessUnitTypes option:selected").val(); };
            // var businessUnitTypeId =  $("#BusinessUnitTypes option:selected").val();

        var lastSelectedId,
            inlineEditParam = {
                keys: true,
                extraparam: {
                    businessUnitTypeId: function() { return $("#BusinessUnitTypes option:selected").val(); }
                }
            },
            $grid = $('#list');


        $('#list').jqGrid({
            url: '<%: Url.Action("GetBusinessUnits", "BusinessUnit")%>',
            postData: {
                businessUnitTypeId: function () { return $("#BusinessUnitTypes option:selected").val(); }
            },
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['ID', 'Name', 'Fax', 'Email', "Employees"],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'BusinessUnitId', index: 'BusinessUnitId', hidden: true, editable: false, key: true },
                { name: 'BusinessUnitName', index: 'BusinessUnitName', width: 200, editable: true, edittype: 'text' },
                { name: 'Fax', index: 'Fax', width: 80, align: 'right', edittype: 'text', editable: true },
                { name: 'Email', index: 'Email', width: 200, editable: true, edittype: 'text' },
                { name: 'NumberOfEmployees', index: 'NumberOfEmployees', width: 70, editable: false}],
            rowNum: 30,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: '#pager',
            gridview: true,
            sortname: 'BusinessUnitName',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "asc",
            caption: "Edit",
            width: 700,
            height: "auto",
            onSelectRow: function (id) {
                if (id && id !== lastSelectedId) {
                    $(this).restoreRow(lastSelectedId);
                    lastSelectedId = id;
                }
                $(this).jqGrid('editRow', id, inlineEditParam);

            },
            editurl: '<%: Url.Action("Save", "BusinessUnit")%>'
        });
        // change defaults of delGridRow to use short for for navGrid
        $.extend($.jgrid.del, {
            width: 'auto',
            url: '<%:Url.Action("Delete", "BusinessUnit")%>'
        });

        // create navigator bar
        $grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
            { add: true, del: true, edit: false, search: false });

        // add buttons to navigator bar
        $('#list').jqGrid('inlineNav', {
            edit: false,
            addParams: { addRowParams: inlineEditParam }
        });
    }

</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correct you try to use [inline editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing) in the project. The method `navGrid` add teh navigator bar and it can be used to add "Delete" button. To add "Add" button which can be used to add empty new row and use inline editing to fill the data you need use [inlineNav](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#inlinenav) *after* call of `navGrid`. The corresponding code will be about the following:

```
$('#list').jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
    { add: true, del: true, edit: false, search: false },
    {}, // Edit
    {}, // Add
    { width: 'auto', url: '<%:Url.Action("Delete", "BusinessUnit")%>' });
$('#list').jqGrid('inlineNav', {
    edit: false,
    addParams: {
        addRowParams: {
            keys: true,
            extraparam: {
                businessUnitTypeId: function () {
                    return $("#BusinessUnitTypes option:selected").val();
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**UPDATED**: By the way you can define a variable and use it for both adding and editing of rows:

```
var lastSelectedId,
    inlineEditParam = {
        keys: true,
        extraparam: {
            businessUnitTypeId: function () {
                return $("#BusinessUnitTypes option:selected").val();
            }
        }
    },
    $grid = $('#list');

$grid.jqGrid({
    url: '<%: Url.Action("GetBusinessUnits", "BusinessUnit")%>',
    ... // all other parameters
    height: "auto",
    onSelectRow: function (id) {
        if (id && id !== lastSelectedId) {
            $(this).jqGrid('restoreRow', lastSelectedId);
            lastSelectedId = id;
        }
        $(this).jqGrid('editRow', id, inlineEditParam);
    },
    editurl: '<%: Url.Action("Save", "BusinessUnit")%>'
});

// change defaults of delGridRow to use short for for navGrid
$.extend($.jgrid.del, {
    width: 'auto',
    url: '<%:Url.Action("Delete", "BusinessUnit")%>'
});

// create navigator bar
$grid.jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
    { add: true, del: true, edit: false, search: false });

// add buttons to navigator bar
$grid.jqGrid('inlineNav', '#pager', {
    edit: false,
    addParams: { addRowParams: inlineEditParam }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for that. However I am getting an exception the the addParams when the page loads; SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'indexOf' 
[+]  businessUnitTypeId function() { return $("#BusinessUnitTypes option:selected").val(); } Object, (Function)

Comment: Typically you see the line number where the error take place. Which versions of jQuery and jqGrid you used? Please replace `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` to `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` and repeat your test. The error message shows the `businessUnitTypeId` will be interpreted as `string` instead of `function`. Do you posted the full code which you used or you used `serializeGridData` or `serializeRowData` where you explicitly call `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: I am using version 4.3.1 and the error is on line 8632. I will post the latest code in the question section.

Comment: @arame3333: It's error in `pager` parameter of `navButtonAdd`. You should use it in the form ` $('#list').jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#pager', ...)`. Probably you used it not as `'#pager'`. The code is not in the code which I posted or which you posted.

Comment: I do not have any code for navButtonAdd. I can see it is falling over in that part of the jqGrid script but I do not know why. I posted all my client side code.

Comment: @arame3333 The usage of ` $('#list').jqGrid('inlineNav', {...})` is wrong in your code. If sould be changed to ` $('#list').jqGrid('inlineNav', '#pager', {...})`. It was typing error in my code. I fixed it in my answer

Comment: That works, thank you. For the navigator bar I also had to set add: false and for the inlineNav I had to put in add: true. The one final thing I could not do is order the buttons, of which I would like as add, delete, refresh. I would be grateful if you can show me how to do that last piece, reordering the sequence of the code simply removed the add button altogether!

Comment: @arame3333: You can *move* the buttons very easy in another position. You should just examine the ids of buttons (`pager_del`, `pager_iladd` and so on). The standard jQuery functions like jQuery.append, jQuery.before, jQuery, insert etc *move* the elements.

Comment: @arame3333: Look at [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11742728/315935) for example.

Comment: I was surprised that was the answer but you are right, it is very easy.